# JST function attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I write own taglib and i want use this in my jsp page. But I have problem with transfer string declared like this `<%! String test= "lot of print test"; %>`  to page.

My .tld

`<function>
        <name>Upper</name> 
        <function-class>my.ChangeCase</function-class> 
        <function-signature> java.lang.String Upper(java.lang.String) </function-signature>
    </function>`

my .java

```
public static String Upper(String text) {
        String up;
        up = text.toUpperCase();

        return up;
    }
```

my .jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/newTag" %>
upper${my: Upper("how send string here?")}
```

Question is how send string to function `Upper` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `upper${my:Upper(test)}`.

Side note, you can simplify your function as

```
public static String Upper(String text) {
    return text.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: I try this but not work only print upper without "lot of print test"

Comment: The code should be ok, either you didn't register your function properly, or something is missing from jsp page. Check out [this simple tutorial](http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/) and try to find what's missing.

Comment: Try with this `<%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/newTag.tld" %>`